# ⚡Scrambled emoji tale ️ #️4️

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, emoji

This is **"Scrambled emoji tale #️4️"**. This time, this one should be fairly easy.

The story  below ⬇️ was sliced ✂️ in a number of parts and scrambled .

From the fragments below, can you retell it entirely and correctly using all the fragments, in the correct order?

Also, who are the characters?

---

## ‍‍‍ Cast:

### ➕

### ➖

### ➕

### ‍️

### ➗2️➕➗2️

### ➗2️➕➗2️

### ➕↕️

### ➗2️➕➗2️

### ‍⚡‍♂️

### ➗3️➕➗3️➕➗3️

### ⏩

### ⚡

### ️️

### ‍♂️

### ➕

### ️

### ➗3️

---

## ️ Filming locations:

### ⛰️⬇️↔️

### ️

### ️

---

## Actions performed by characters:

Many of these are performed multiple times.

### ☠️

### ➡️️

### ⚗️✝️

### ✊️

### ⬇️️

### ☝↩️

### ➡️

### ➡️

### ️️️️

### ️

### ⚡‍♂️

### ️

### ⬆️️

### ➡️️

---

More than 1 month and no answers yet!

So here are some hints ⭐:

1. [2022/11/17] The characters are very scrambled. Almost all of them are nameless and the emojis describes how they look like.
2. [2022/12/05] The answer is something published in 1988-1990. Although there were some republications in different formats.
3. [2022/12/12] It has something to do with Ancient Greece.

Comment: is each member of the cast scrambled as well? Like, first name might on a different row than last name? And does it contain the roles?

Comment: @JGibbers They are very scrambled. Almost all of them are nameless and the emojis describes how they look like (hint #1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about everything as I'm unfamiliar with the material but this scrambled emoji tale comes from

> The video game [Altered Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Beast)

**Characters**
➕

> Slow Foot

➖

> Headless Horror

➕

> Hammer Demon

> Grave Master

> Dark Unicorn

‍️

> Zeus?

➗2️➕➗2️

> Chicken Stinger

> Athena

> Aggar

➗2️➕➗2️

> Saw Fish

➕↕️

> Weretiger

➗2️➕➗2️

> Round Leech

> Werebear

> Rad Boar

‍⚡‍♂️

> Sorcerer Neff (who taunts you throughout the game)

➗3️➕➗3️➕➗3️

> Rattle Tail

⏩

> Werewolf

⚡

> Weredragon

️️

> Octeyes

> Crocodile Worm

> Moldy Snail

> Cave Needle

‍♂️

> Centurion

➕

> Three-headed blue wolf

️

> Dove which appears at the end of the game and transforms into Athena

> Neff

> Gory Goat

➗3️

> Unsure, possibly Skinny Orcus

> Rock Turtle

**Filming Locations**

⛰️⬇️↔️

> Underground Cavern

️

> Graveyard

> Netherworld's Sanctum

> Zeus' Crystal Ball

> Cave?

️

> Netherworld Fortress

**Actions**

☠️

> Death

> Fighting enemies

> Punch

➡️️

> Streak?

⚗️✝️

> Athena is show to be transformed into the dove while hanging from a cross, I think this is what is being shown here.

✊️

> Fighting for Athena?

⬇️️

> Exits through a hole at the end of a level

☝↩️

> Centurion is resurrected and commanded by Zeus to return Athena

➡️

> Moving towards Athena

➡️

> Contact with three spirit balls changes you into the altered beast.

> Unsure

️️️️

> Probably indicating the fight with Octeyes

> There are spirit balls throughout the game which increase your strength

️

> Flame streak

> Fireball

> Pillar of Fire

> At the end, it is centurion in werewolf form who falls in love

⚡‍♂️

> Lightning Bolt

> Jump

️

> There's a distinctive shot in the end credits of a director calling for cut, the main character taking off a wolf mask and the cast go for beers.

⬆️️

> At the start of a level, player emerges from a hole.

> Unsure

➡️️

> Move towards the dove

Useful References

> Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnFE52Dcmr8
>  Manual: https://manuals.sega.com/genesismini/pdf/ALTERED_BEAST.pdf

Comment: Rot13 - Oenib, nygrerq ornfg vf gur pbeerpg nafjre. Abj, whfg svk n srj bs gur qrgnvyf gung ner hapregnva naq lbh ner qbar.